# AngularJS end-to-end tests using Karma with a static file instead of server

Tags: javascript, testing, angularjs, karma-runner

I have end-to-end tests for my AngularJS app and I'm using Karma as my test runner. I currently have the following in my Karma config:

```
config.proxies = {
  '/': 'http://localhost:9292/'
};
```

I have to separately start up a simple Rack app that serves my single static AngularJS HTML file. I want to have end-to-end tests that test a static file, much like loading `file:///Users/sarah/my-app/index.html`. I've tried not setting a proxy and doing `browser().navigateTo 'index.html'` in my tests, but the tests all fail because my `element` calls "did not match any elements". It looks like the index.html page is not getting loaded.

I've also tried setting a proxy where `'/': 'file:///Users/sarah/my-app/` and then doing `browser().navigateTo '/index.html'` in my tests, but that failed with the error "options.host and options.port or options.target are required". While I guess I could set the port to 80, there is no host--that's the point.

My goal with this is I want to have my end-to-end tests run automatically on [Semaphore](https://semaphoreapp.com/), where my AngularJS unit tests currently run. The unit tests are different because they don't require an instance of my app to be accessed.

Is what I'm wanting to do possible? If not, is there any way I can run both unit and end-to-end tests of my AngularJS app on Semaphore without hosting my app on some public server that Semaphore can access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I got my end result: automated end-to-end testing on Semaphore. The trick was to create a separate test-index.html that uses a test version of my app. It has `<html ng-app="TestMyApp">` instead of `<html ng-app="MyApp">`. It also includes the following extra JavaScript that my actual index.html does not:

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular-mocks.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="spec/e2e/test_api_app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My test_api_app.js is actually compiled from CoffeeScript by the karma-coffee-preprocessor, but here is the CoffeeScript source:

```
angular.module('TestMyApp', ['MyApp', 'ngMockE2E']).run ($httpBackend) ->
  $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://some-api-my-app-uses/images').respond
    status: 'success'
    images: [...]
  // more mocked calls MyApp makes
```

Then in my karma-e2e.config.js, I don't set `urlRoot`, and the only proxies I set are just because my CoffeeScript app files live in a coffee directory and the app expects the compiled Javascript to be at /js:

```
config.proxies = {
  '/base/js/app.js': 'http://localhost:' + config.port +
                     '/base/coffee/app.js',
  // other mapping from the URLs my app expects to exist to where
  // karma-coffee-preprocessor puts the compiled JavaScript
```

The neat thing here is that Karma runs a server itself, so it hosts my static test-index.html file for me. In my proxies above, the `'http://localhost:' + config.port` part is referring to the Karma server. `config.port` is defined elsewhere in my Karma config to be 9876.

I defined my Karma `config.files` to include:

```
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js',
'http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular-mocks.js',
'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',
'coffee/**/*.coffee',
'http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular-resource.min.js',
'spec/e2e/**/*_spec.coffee',
'spec/e2e/test_api_app.coffee',
{
  pattern: 'css/*.css',
  watched: true,
  included: false,
  served: true
},
{
  pattern: 'img/spinner.gif',
  watched: true,
  included: false,
  served: true
},
{
  pattern: 'test-index.html',
  watched: true,
  included: false,
  served: true
}
```

Then in my end-to-end tests, I do:

```
browser().navigateTo '/base/test-index.html#/'
```

I have a package.json with the following script:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "bundle exec sass scss/my-app.scss css/my-app.css ; ./node_modules/.bin/karma start spec/karma-unit-functional.config.js --single-run --browsers Firefox ; ./node_modules/.bin/karma start spec/karma-e2e.config.js --single-run --browsers Firefox"
}
```

I compile the CSS file so that when I run end-to-end tests it doesn't give a 404 error about my-app.css not existing. My build commands on Semaphore are:

```
bundle install
npm install
npm test
```

And the tests pass!